# No resource identifier found for attribute 'border_width' for component CircleImageView

Tags: android

How do I resolve the following compiler errors:

> Error:(127) No resource identifier found for attribute 'border_width' in package 'talkie.feedback'
>
> Error:(127) No resource identifier found for attribute 'border_color' in package 'talkie.feedback'
>
> Error:(134, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'border_color' with value '@color/white').

**XML**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView 
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
  android:id="@+id/imageView" 
  android:layout_width="150dp" 
  android:layout_height="150dp" 
  android:src="@mipmap/cat_judges" 
  app:border_width="2dp" 
  app:border_color="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: you should use civ_border_width and civ_border_color as stated in https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See sample in **usage** section from [Readme on Github](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/profile_image"
  android:layout_width="96dp"
  android:layout_height="96dp"
  android:src="@drawable/profile"
  app:civ_border_width="2dp"
  app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

Here used `app:civ_border_width="2dp"` instead of `app:border_width="2dp"` and `app:civ_border_color` instead of `app:border_color`.